# Calculate and attach date-differences for equal strings in column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series

I have a dataframe containing one name-variable in which there are different duplicate strings, then some numeric variables and one date variable. First off, I'm trying to find out whether I can create a new column that for all strings with same value, subtracts the lowest date from every other date and therefore has a numeric value (days). If that is possible, I want to correlate one of the numeric variables of choice with the new day-variable but, again, aggregated over the same string-value or "person". Regarding that, I wouldn't mind having the result of the correlation listed in every row of the string, since I'll aggregate over strings, later, anyway. I know this probably sounds really confusing, and I hope the little example I set up, which already contains the "correct" values, will help with understanding my problem.

```
names <- c("Richard", "Richard", "Mortimer", "Mortimer", "Mortimer", "Elizabeth", "Elizabeth")
num1 <- c(0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4)
num2 <- c(0.6, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3)
num3 <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5)
date <- c("2016-08-09", "2014-07-16", "2014-05-17", "2014-04-17", "2013-04-13", "2013-04-10", "2013-04-01")

myframe <- data.frame(names, num1, num2, num3, date)

dayssignedin <- c(755, 0, 399, 369, 0, 9, 0)

desiredoutput1 <- data.frame(myframe, dayssignedin)

num1correlates <- c(1,1, 0.9800646, 0.9800646, 0.9800646, -1, -1)

desiredoutputfinal <- data.frame(desiredoutput, num1correlates)
```

Comment: You are correct, I made a mistake.

Comment: num1correlates would correlate the values of one Person on num1 with the values of the same person on dayssignedin. It is only repeated, because I couldn't think of any other way to store that information.

Comment: Thank you so much. So imagine the values were jumping heights. And time passing by is equal to training. Then num1correlates is calculated for each individual separately, for example for Mortimer by taking cor(c(0.8, 0.9, 0.2), c(399, 369, 0)) to asses the link between training and jumping height. It's probably confusing that I tripled the values, since there actually is only one correlation, but I thought that was a convenient way to store the data.

Comment: It comes from taking "2014-04-17" - "2013-04-13", which is key to the problem I have. It is also the reason why I can't simply take max and min.

Comment: So basically I always want to subtract the min from every date of one person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` one way is to convert `date` to Date object, subtract `date` with `min`imum date for each `names` and then calculate corelation between `num1` and `dayssignedin`.

```
library(dplyr)

myframe %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  mutate(dayssignedin = as.integer(date - min(date)), 
         num1correlates = cor(num1, dayssignedin))

#  names      num1  num2  num3 date       dayssignedin num1correlates
#  <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>            <int>          <dbl>
#1 Richard     0.8   0.6   0.5 2016-08-09          755          1    
#2 Richard     0.1   0.3   0.4 2014-07-16            0          1    
#3 Mortimer    0.8   0.8   0.4 2014-05-17          399          0.980
#4 Mortimer    0.9   0.8   0.5 2014-04-17          369          0.980
#5 Mortimer    0.2   0.5   0.8 2013-04-13            0          0.980
#6 Elizabeth   0.2   0.5   0.6 2013-04-10            9         -1    
#7 Elizabeth   0.4   0.3   0.5 2013-04-01            0         -1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is awesome. Definitely have to learn to use dplyr.